# ftp file transfer using vb.net without any third party tools

Tags: vb.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am writing the code using vb.net for file transfer from remote machine to local machine with out using any third party tools

This my code

```
Dim reqFTP As FtpWebRequest
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim filename1 As String
    Dim ftpserverip As String
    Dim ftpuserid As String
    Dim ftpPassword As String
    Try
        filename1 = TxtRemoteFile.Text
        filepath = TxtLocalFile.Text
        filename = Locfname.Text
        ftpserverip = TxtServerIP.Text
        ftpuserid = TxtUserName.Text
        ftpPassword = TxtPwd.Text
        Dim outputStream As FileStream = New FileStream((filepath + ("\\" + filename)), FileMode.Create)
        reqFTP = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri(("ftp://" _
                            + (ftpserverip + ("/" + filename1))))), FtpWebRequest)
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
        reqFTP.UseBinary = True
        reqFTP.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftpuserid, ftpPassword)
        Dim response As FtpWebResponse = CType(reqFTP.GetResponse, FtpWebResponse)

        outputStream.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

but am getting error like" remote server returned error :(550) fi

Comment: Are you sure you have write permissions on the ftp server?

Comment: I'd turn on 'break on all errors' and see which line it fails on. Also: The 550 error is a message from the server stating that the account you have currently logged in as does not have permission to perform the action you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was not including httpdocs in the remote path.
Example:
ftp://ftp.websitename.com/httpdocs/filenametocopy.txt

```
System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.websitename.com/httpdocs/filenametocopy.txt")
```

Permission was denied because i was trying to write the file outside the root directory.

Comment: `filenametocopy.txt` is not available at that path.